# Get SharePoint user name and put into a field on NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a newform that has the user name autopopulate on opening the form.  I have tried using `SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser` however I keep getting an error saying unidentified or Null.  I am using sharepoint foundation 2013, and I cannot use Visual studio, only Designer with jquery and javascript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure jQuery is loaded as its working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
  var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
  var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
  $.ajax({
    url : requestUri,
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers : requestHeaders,
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
  });

  function onSuccess(data, request){
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    $('#textboxid').val(loginName);
  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert("error");
  }
</script>
```